# Why does my code keep stopping?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

I made a Python script, that reads a text file then goes to a url, and adds the extension in the text file to the url. The problem is the script keeps stopping before it is done reading the file. I cant figure out why.

```
import urllib
f = open("extension/1.txt", 'r')

for x in f.readline():    
    a = f.readline()
    url = "http://www.link.com/whatever/%s" % a
    print url
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, a)
```

Comment: It's done when it stops. Maybe you could restate your question?

Comment: How far does it get? which url/file line does it stop on?

Comment: Is the script exiting, or is it just hanging at a particular point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By calling `for x in f.readline():`, you'll be going through the `string` that is the first line of the file as an iterable and then grabbing a new line for each character in the first line via `a = f.readline()`. I don't think this is your intent.

The `file` object `f` is iterable itself, so you can simply do the following:

```
for line in f:
    value = line.rstrip('\n')
    url = "http://www.link.com/whatever/%s" % value
    print url
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, value)  # Not sure why you want to send value (your a) here
```

Comment: The file I am downloading is a swf file which is why I want it that way.

Comment: Agreed. During each iteration a line is read into x then a line is read into a. Effectively two lines read during each iteration and only the second one used.

Comment: To clarify for @Max00355, we don't fully "agree" @GrantVS. As I mention, it's not actually reading 2 lines for every loop of the iteration, it is reading the first line into `x` and then reading **one line** for each character of `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does the following:

1. Reads one line from the file (`f.readline()`).
2. For each character in that line (`for x in f.readline()`), read an additional line (`a = f.readline()`) and process it.

Thus, it will only process as many lines as there are characters in the first line of the file, and the first line will never be processed.

You probably want to write that loop as:

```
with open("extension/1.txt") as f:
    for a in f:
        a = a.strip()
        url = "http://www.link.com/whatever/%s" % a
        print url
        urllib.urlretrieve(url, a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps reading all the lines at first like so:

```
fp = open(the_file)
lines = fp.readlines()
fp.close()

for line in lines:
    do something
```